# Creating and using Laravel 4 commands

Tags: command-line, laravel, laravel-4

EDIT: Figured out where I was going wrong and placed an answer at the end

I'm trying to create a Laravel Command, I can see it's changed considerably from "tasks" in Laravel 3. However I can't seem to get it to run. These are the steps I have taken:

> php artisan command:make Import

Returns

> Command created successfully

The file in the commands directory is then created and I have slightly modified to return "Hello World" like so:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class Import extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'command:import';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array(
            array('example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            array('example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null),
        );
    }

}
```

However when I try and run the command like so:

> php artisan Import

I get the following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException] Command "Import" is not defined.

I have tried it with and without capitals as well as naming it "ImportCommand" since the documentation names its command "FooCommand" but with no luck.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually figured this out. Further down the documentation it states that you must register your command in "app/start/artisan.php" using the following method:

```
Artisan::add(new import);
```

Also the name you give in your command class is significant as that's what you need to use to call it. So I should have actually been calling it like so:

```
php artisan command:import
```

One final thing. What the fire() returns is unimportant, to return strings you must echo them.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Do you need to fix the case of "import"?

Answer (score 7):

try this.

```
protected function getArguments()
{
    return [];
}

protected function getOptions()
{
    return [];
}
```

also add this in `/app/start/artisan.php`

```
Artisan::add(new ParseCommand);
```

then Run Command on Root directory

```
./artisan command:import;
```

Comment: This worked for me. Laravel automatically inserted a default argument in getArguments method

Answer (score 2):

In newer Laravel versions there isn't an `import` command. You just have to do the following two thing:

1. Register your command in `app/start/artisan.php`:

   ```php
   Artisan::add(new Import);
   ```
2. Run the command in Artisan:

   ```
   php artisan command:name Import
   ```

Answer (score 0):

there's a mis-understanding on Artisan commands because of the used wording.

In your case you choose : 'command:import' as a name of one of your 'Import' commands.

Think about it as an object, with methods.

### If "Import" has many commands:

you can use as command name > protected $name = 'import:csv';

another command would be > protected $name = 'import:txt';

and > protected $name = 'import:contacts';

so your commands with "Import" nature are better organised.

and when you request , you see your commands organised as a single entity.

### If not,

and you have only a single command then give your command a single clear name. protected $name = 'import';